# How to set tooltip in Bar3d in Jfreechart

Tags: java, tooltip, jfreechart

I am using `JfreeChart` and `3D bar`. I want to get tooltip for each bar in graph. I have tried

```
 BarRenderer3D renderer = new BarRenderer3D(15,15);
 renderer.setMaxBarWidth(0.5);
 renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator("tooltip goes here", DateFormat.getDateInstance()));
```

My Bar is horizontal with Values on X axis
But I am not getting any result.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [*Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `new BarRenderer3D()`, pass `true` for the `tooltips` parameter to the [`ChartFactory.createBarChart3D()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createBarChart3D%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method used to create the chart and get a reference to the renderer created by the factory. Optionally, replace the generator; see the default format string, [`DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT_STRING`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator.html#line.62), for the standard parameters.

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(…, true, …);
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
BarRenderer3D renderer = (BarRenderer3D) plot.getRenderer();
// optionally
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
```